# Ruby + Imap: searching a subject with special characters doesn't work

Tags: ruby, imap, gmail-imap

When using Ruby + IMAP and trying to search a subject with special chars:

```
imap.uid_search(['SUBJECT', subject, 'NOT', 'SEEN'])
```

where subject is "Olá", it will fail with:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
from /Users/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1266:in `==='
```

Specifying the second parameter of uid_search, which is the charset, also doesn't work.

Subjects without special characters works fine. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: can you put `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of the Ruby script where you're instantiating the `imap` object? (maybe that's a silly suggestion)

Comment: @SeamusAbshere Unfortunately it results in the same error.

Comment: what's your `Encoding.default_external` ?

Comment: and does http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/914604 fix it?

Comment: @SeamusAbshere Encoding.default_external is UTF-8. And no, that patch doesn't fix it. I also tried updating to ruby 1.9.3p392. No luck at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This replicates the problem (with the same regexp that `net/imap` uses):

```
# encoding: ascii-8bit
a = /[\x80-\xff\r\n]/n
a =~ "olá".force_encoding('utf-8') # incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

Two possibilities:

1. Add `# encoding: ascii-8bit` to the top of your script
2. Force the string's encoding over to `ascii-8bit`:

   imap.uid_search(['SUBJECT', subject.force_encoding('ascii-8bit'), 'NOT', 'SEEN'])

Comment: I did that and this error is shown:  C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/imap.rb:1226:in `get_tagged_response': Could not parse command (Net::IMAP::BadResponseError)